# How to use generic foreign keys with unique together in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have 2 models in Django which inherit from an abstract base class.

For example, my abstract base model is common_content and my 2 models which inherit from it are article and interview.

```
class commonContent:
     slug = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_slug])
     css = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     html_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
     ..... and so on, there are few more properties related to meta tags

   class Meta:
    abstract = True

class Article(CommonContent):
   related_content = CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class Interview(CommonContent):
   related_content = CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I have a model of Category which I want to link to both Interviews and Articles(both have common categories).

Following is my category model:-

```
class Category():
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, validators=[validate_slug])
display_text = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I tried link my Category model to Article and Interview using generic foreign keys in following model:-

```
class CategoryCommonContentMapping(BaseModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    limit= models.Q(app_label = 'binger', model = 'interview') | models.Q(app_label = 'binger', model = 'article')
    type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to = limit,default='')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='')
    contentObject = GenericForeignKey('type', 'object_id')
    score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Now i try using unique together in this model in following way:

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('category', 'type','object_id'),)
```

But something is missing and I cannot link my article/interviews to my categories.

I am new to django and was trying things reading the documentations. So basically what I want is that I can link Category to Interview/Article so that I can filter them on basis of categories on my page i.e. say when a category is selected content(Interview/Article) should be visible only for that category. I already wrote the filter code and it was working fine before using generic keys(I kept Interview/Article in the same model).

Comment: I would get rid of the inheritance of the content models, and I would use only a single type of model with an extra column defining what type of record is that (article, interview) - that will provide you more flexibility when you will add a new type of content (no need to create a new db table), and also you wont need any GenericForeignKeys, and everything will get more simple.